# using jest to test button clicks work appropriately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to make tests that make sure button clicks work appropriately.

The test suite is like this currently,

```
import React from 'react';
import Customization from 'components/onboarding/customization';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('customization render', () => {
  it('should render the Hero page with no issue', () => {
    render(<Customization />);

    const heading = screen.getByText(
      /All the Moodmap at one place!/i
    );

    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should call onCLick method on click", () => {
    const mockOnClick = jest.fn()

    const {container} = render(<Customization />);

    const button = getByTestId(container, 'alreadyDownloaded');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)


    // const mockOnClick = jest.fn()
    // const utils = render(<Customization onClick={mockOnClick} />)
    // fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/already downloaded ⟶/i))
    // expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
});
```

When running this it makes an error - not sure really,

The component it's testing is like this

```
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import OnboardingSvg from 'components/onboarding/svg/onboardingSvg'
import DataAPI from 'components/onboarding/data-integrations/dataAPI'
import ChromeExtension from "components/onboarding/data-integrations/chromeExtension"
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Customization(){
  const router = useRouter();

  
    
    return (
    <motion.div
    initial={{ opacity: 0, translateY: -15 }}
    animate={{ opacity: 1, translateY: 0 }}
    exit={{ opacity: 0, translateY: -15 }}
    >
    <div className="pb-8 w-full">
      ...
      
  <button
   data-testid = "alreadyDownloaded"
    onClick={() => router.push('/onboarding/settings')}
    className="text-right text-xs text-gray-600 mt-4 italic inline-block focus:outline-none"
  >
    Already downloaded ⟶
  </button>
</div>
      <style jsx>
        {`
          .ct {
            background: linear-gradient(
              -45deg,
              #ee7752,
              #e73c7e,
              #23a6d5,
              #23d5ab
            );
            background-size: 400% 400%;
            animation: gradient 5s ease infinite;
          }
    
          @keyframes gradient {
            0% {
              background-position: 0% 50%;
            }
            50% {
              background-position: 100% 50%;
            }
            100% {
              background-position: 0% 50%;
            }
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </div>
    </motion.div>)}
```

I would have imnagined this would work fine? confused - it searches for the button, clicks it then wants a response with the mock function, but the test sort of breaks?

#### Update referencing post below

Hey there,

This is my new function!

```
import React from 'react';
import Customization from 'components/onboarding/customization';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('customization render', () => {
  it('should render the Hero page with no issue', () => {
    render(<Customization />);

    const heading = screen.getByText(
      /All the Moodmap at one place!/i
    );

    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should call onCLick method on click", () => {
    const mockOnClick = jest.fn()
    render(<Customization onClick={mockOnClick} />)
    const button = screen.getByTestId('alreadyDownloaded');

    // fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/already downloaded ⟶/i))
    // expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    // const button = getByTestId(container, 'alreadyDownloaded');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)


    
   
  })
});
```

The specific error I'm receiving is this,

```
 ● customization render › should call onCLick method on click

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      23 |     // const button = getByTestId(container, 'alreadyDownloaded');
      24 |     fireEvent.click(button);
    > 25 |     expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
         |                         ^
      26 | 
      27 | 
      28 |     

      at Object.<anonymous> (components/onboarding/customization.test.js:25:25)
```

Unsure how to fix this, looking at documentation now!

Comment: What error happens? And how does the test “sort of breaks”? Please include all necessary information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test that your function is called, you need to pass it into the component somehow and then call it in the component. Right now you're mocking a function, but there's no relationship between this mocked function and the component because your `onClick` in the `button` is using a function declared there, rather than referencing a function that jest can mock and spyOn.

One approach would be to refactor the component like this:

- pass in a function that calls `router.push` as a prop to this component (you can create a default argument to avoid having to pass it every time.) Let's assume you name it something like `handleClick`.
- in the button, instead of declaring a function there and then, call the `handleClick` function received as a prop (depending on whether you care about the browser event, you might need to do `onClick={(e) => handleClick()}`)
- in your tests, you can mock the function, and then pass it into the component as a prop in your `render` function as you've done with the commmented out code.
- This should then allow you to assert that your mock has been called.

Another approach would be to just mock the `router` module itself and then define a `mockImplementation` that calls a mocked function you declare in your tests. This would avoid you having to pass in an extra dependency, but is a little more involved. [The official docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks) have a good guide on how to achieve this.